# Turning a line layer into a polygon layer and automatically adding an attribute

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, line

I have been given a .DXF file of a site which has been split into a 10 x 10 grid system consisting of 910 individual squares.

In order to create these squares the person who made the grid made 30 lines running north / south and 31 lines running east / west and where these intersected became the boxes. (I've tried to attach a photo but apologies if it doesn't appear properly)

Anyway I would like to create a polygon shapefile with several attribute columns based on these boxes.

One of which is a label for each box - North / South squares are numbers, East / West are letters so where these intersect you would get a cell ID i.e. I10

How can I create a layer creating polygons from the line layer and label these accordingly as automatically as possible using QGIS 3.16?

Comment: What software system are you using?

Comment: sorry I am using QGIS -  3.16

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please be sure to specify the GIS software in use within the body and tags of every Question you ask. You can [Edit] the Question with the previous link or the "Edit" button beneath the Question.